# Unable to find the error in a simple code that determines seasons

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a code that outputs the season based on a day and month as input based on the following parameters:

Spring: March 20 - June 20
Summer: June 21 - September 21
Autumn: September 22 - December 20
Winter: December 21 - March 19

for e.g., if the input is:
April
11

the output is:
Spring

But every time I enter September 31 as the input instead of Invalid, I get Autumn and not able to figure out how to correct the code so as to reflect that Sept 31 is not a valid date. Any help would be appreciated. Here is the code I am working with:

```
# Gather month and day inputs
month = input()
day = int(input())

# Determine the start and end dates for each season
spring_start = (3, 20)
spring_end = (6, 20)
summer_start = (6, 21)
summer_end = (9, 21)
autumn_start = (9, 22)
autumn_end = (12, 20)
winter_start = (12, 21)
winter_end = (3, 19)

# Create a tuple 'months_list'
months_list = ('January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
               'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December')

# Validate the input month
if month not in months_list:
    print("Invalid")
else:
    # Validate the input day
    if day < 1 or day > 31:
        print("Invalid")
    else:
        # Convert the month to its matching numeric value
        month_to_num = {
            "January": 1, "February": 2, "March": 3, "April": 4, "May": 5, "June": 6,
            "July": 7, "August": 8, "September": 9, "October": 10, "November": 11, "December": 12
        }
        numeric_month = month_to_num[month]

        # Determine the season based on the input date
        if (numeric_month == 3 and day >= 20) or (numeric_month > 3 and numeric_month < 6) or (numeric_month == 6 and day <= 20):
            print("Spring")
        elif (numeric_month == 6 and day >= 21) or (numeric_month > 6 and numeric_month < 9) or (numeric_month == 9 and day <= 21):
            print("Summer")
        elif (numeric_month == 9 and day >= 22) or (numeric_month > 9 and numeric_month < 12) or (numeric_month == 12 and day <= 20):
            print("Autumn")
        else:
            print("Winter")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some code that will print "Invalid" if it's September and the day is 31:

```
elif (numeric_month == 9 and day >= 22) or (numeric_month > 9 and numeric_month < 12) or (numeric_month == 12 and day <= 20):
            if (day == 31):
                return print("Invalid")
            print("Autumn")
        else:
            print("Winter")
```

Comment: `day >= 31` What?  Plenty of months have 31 days.  Why would you say day 31 is invalid?

Comment: Sorry the edits were just pending but I put another answer if the OG wanted it just for September!

Comment: Hi Kai, thank you for your input on this. Much appreciated. I was able to correct the code based on the answers received here.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you for your interest in this question. You are right about many months having 31 days but for the purposes of this code we are talking about September having day 31 which it does not, hence the 'Invalid' output.

Answer (score 0):

September 31st meets the first condition of the Autumn `if` block...

> (numeric_month == 9 and day >= 22)

You could fix that by

> (numeric_month == 9 and day >= 22 and day <= 30)

Also, your code will never print "Invalid", fixing this would print "Winter" instead.

You need to add the conditions for winter as an `elif` like the other seasons, then your `else` becomes `print("Invalid date")`

Comment: Great, I was able to fix the issue after all, based on the feedback received here. Thank you for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: My pleasure. If my answer solved your problem, consider marking it accepted with the tick on the left.